# discord.js How to fix variables coming back as undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have scanned through the extensive list of questions asking similar things, but none of them have been able to solve this problem in this context.

**Essentially**, I'm attempting to build a blackjack command for a bot in `discord.js`, and so far, the flow looks like this: it takes the names and id's of all of the players and then passes them into the function that handles each game. First, three functions are defined. One that finds the value of a hand (the total of the cards) and one that adds a new card. A `RichEmbed` is created that will be edited many times, and the first time it is created in a game, it will give each person their hand, evaluate it, and then put it in the embed.

**The problem is**: the variables storing players' hands and hand values come back as undefined during initialization, even though I have tested that they can be output from the same place in the code, and that the functions that give them their data also work. What is causing them to be undefined, and why is it only those two variables? The others work just fine.

**My code**:

```js
async function bj(players_id, players_names) {
            var pc = players_id.length; //player count
            var turn; //whose turn is it? based on id
            var disp; //text to be shown in embed; game status.
            var hands = []; //each player's hand
            var handValues = []; //the sum of the cards in a hand
            var cards = ["A", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "J", "Q", "K"]; //all possible cards
            var ing = []; //is player in game? / have they busted?

            turn = players_id[0];
            var disp_dir = "React with �� to hit and ✋ to stand.";
            disp = `Currently ${message.member.guild.members.get(turn).displayName}'s turn.\n${disp_dir}`;

            function addCard() {return(cards[Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length)])}; //simply grabs a card from the list of cards

            function findHandValue(handValue, currentCards) { //takes two inputs, one is the current hand value, the other is a list of card values. finds the total value of the hand and returns it.
                var val = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < currentCards.length; i++) {
                    card = currentCards[i];
                    if (card == "A") {
                        if (handValue > 21) {val += 1;} else {val += 11;};
                    } else if (card == "J" || card == "Q" || card == "K") {
                        val += 10;
                    } else {val += card;};
                };
                return(val);
            };

            function makeEmbed(first) { //constructs the embed that will be used to show the game. param. first tells whether it is the first time the embed is being constrcuted in a game.
                var bjg = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setTitle("Blackjack Game")
                .setDescription(`Initiated by ${players_names[0]}`)
                .addField("Status", `${disp}`)
                .setThumbnail("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/563578266984775681/657323254813425674/cards.jpg")
                .setColor("DC134C")
                .setFooter("Valkyrie", client.avatarURL)
                .setTimestamp();

                if (first == true) {
                    for (i = 0; i < pc; i++) { //should be creating each player's hand
                        ing.push(true); //this one works
                        hands.push([addCard(), addCard()]); //but for some reason, this one returns undefined
                        handValues.push(findHandValue(0, hands[i])); //and this one
                        bjg.addField(`${players_names[i]}'s Hand`, `${hands[i]}\n\nValue: ${handValues[i]}`); //spits out undefined in almost every place, including the player_name[i]
                        var bjs = message.channel.send(bjg);
                        return(bjs);
                    };
                };
            };
            var bjs = await makeEmbed(true); //and this stuff works fine
            await bjs.react("��");
            await bjs.react("✋");
        };
        if (args[0] == "quick") {
            message.reply("You've started a game of solo blackjack against a bot!");
            await bj([message.author.id], [message.member.displayName]);
```

Apologies that that is lengthy, but all of it is necessary to show what it's doing and to help pinpoint the error's origin.

**Finally, this is the result**

[image: The result]

**Extra Note**

After extremely extensive debugging, I've found that the problem is coming from the line
`handValues.push(findHandValue(0, hands[i]));`, and the problem is that it changes `i` by +2, which only raises more questions. A small band-aid fix was to set another variable to `i` at the start and then reset `i` to the other one after the line.

Comment: Why are you calling `return(bjs);` inside a for-loop?

Comment: Wait a minute... I stg